# PHP - How to use GeoLite2 IP CSV databases in MySql?

Tags: php, mysql, geolocation, geocoding, maxmind

How do you get the CSV databases of GeoLite2 City and Country to work?

I have seen you must import it into a table. However I have seen some people takeout the IPv6 addresses. I have also seen some people attempt to combine both the blocks and the location databases...

What I want to do is take an IP and get the GPS coordinate and the City, State, Country data.

What table structure should I use? Once the data is imported how to I do a lookup using a PHP page?

Comment: What is your use-case and what have you tried?

Comment: Uhh I don't even known so far what I've tried. :S I wanna start from scratch on how to get it to work.

Comment: @EWit Okay, so I have imported the City databases. Now I am unsure as to how to do a lookup of an IP?

Comment: You might want to check if http://lite.ip2location.com has IPv6 support or not. Their format is easier to query by database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to figure it out... I removed all IPv6 IP records. Then I calculated the start and ending IP ranges and figured out where the IP fit in there. After that it was self explanatory.